# Return Value for Most Recent Date Based on Condition in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I am looking to return the value for the most recent/latest date for each type (Type A, Type B). I have tried several formulas and combination of formulas.

Formulas I have tried (Using *Type A* as an example)

- `DMAX` : `=IF(A2="Type A",DMAX(A:C,"Value",B:B),0)` returns `814`
- `VLOOKUP` : `=IF(A2="Type A", VLOOKUP(MAX(B:B),C:C,1,0),0)` returns `#N/A`
- `MAX IF` : `{=MAX(IF(A:A="Type A",C:C,""))}` returns `703`

The values that should be returned are:

- Type A: `219`, the value for 01/05/21 which is the most recent date
- Type B: `505`, the value for 01/05/21 which is the most recent date

This is the data I'm working with:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Type** | **Date** | **Value** |
| **2** | Type A | 01/01/21 | 29 |
| **3** | Type A | 01/02/21 | 703 |
| **4** | Type A | 01/03/21 | 280 |
| **5** | Type A | 01/04/21 | 154 |
| **6** | Type A | 01/05/21 | 219 |
| **7** | Type B | 01/01/21 | 814 |
| **8** | Type B | 01/02/21 | 638 |
| **9** | Type B | 01/03/21 | 811 |
| **10** | Type B | 01/04/21 | 292 |
| **11** | Type B | 01/05/21 | 505 |

*Dates are in U.S. format MM/DD/YY for reference.*

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have the newest version of Excel you can use `FILTER`. First get the unique Types with `=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$11)`, then use something like:

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$11,
(($B$2:$B$11=MAX(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,($A$2:$A$11=E1))))*
($A$2:$A$11=E1)))
```

For example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the most recent version of Excel I have is 2013 and LibreOffice Calc doesn't have this formula, but Google Sheets does so I'll do it in that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways, but I managed to get a similar result by splitting up my formula a little (Note, I randomized my dates some to provide a better test).

I have a column for each type, and one that finds the max date. Then I use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula for the final look up. This is what it looks like.

| Type | Date (Formula) | Date (Result) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type A | `=MAXIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,E9,B1:B10,"<"&DATE(2021,9,15))` | 01/30/21 |
| Type B | `=MAXIFS(B2:B11,A2:A11,E10,B2:B11,"<"&DATE(2021,9,15))` | 01/31/21 |

And then the final result

| Value (Result) | Value (Formula) |
| --- | --- |
| 703 | `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11=E9)*(B2:B11=F9)*(C2:C11))` |
| 811 | `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11=E10)*(B2:B11=F10)*(C2:C11))` |

It's still not perfect but it works using reasonably standard formulas and doesn't rely on anything specific to Excel (which is useful for me).

So my spreadsheet looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Your solution using a combination of the `SUMPRODUCT()` and `MAXIFS()` functions may return the wrong result. For example, if your table has more than one row with `Type A` and date `1/30/21`, then the formula `=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$12=E8;$B$2:$B$12=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$12;$A$2:$A$12;E8);$C$2:$C$12)` will return not the most recent value, but the sum of all values for that day. To get only one value, the formula will have to be slightly complicated - `=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$12=E8;$B$2:$B$12+ROW($B$2:$B$12)/(ROWS(B:B)+1)=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$12+ROW($B$2:$B$12)/(ROWS(B:B)+1);$A$2:$A$12;E8);$C$2:$C$12)`